# Counting with variable base for each digit

Tags: python

Let's say I want to count in a system that has variable bases across the digit positions (this might resemble the Imperial measurement system to some). So for example, I am counting with up to three digits "abc", where b is modulo x, c is modulo y and a can be unlimited, and can be any number. When the "digit" counts up to its base, it returns to zero and the digit on the left increments by one.

What is the convenient way to do this? Of course, this should scale to any number of "digits".
A simple way would be:

```
def count_var(n, m):

    m = m[::-1] # this is inverted for ease of iteration

    l = len(m)
    result = [0] * (l+1)
    for i in range(n):
        result[0] += 1
        for j in range(l):
            if result[j] == m[j]:
                result[j] = 0
                result[j+1] += 1

    return result[::-1]

print(count_var(719, [3,6,5]))
```

Can this be optimized or automated with some built-in? The nested loops seem very slow, but I cannot compare them to anything. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure there is some elegant way of doing some dynamic programming and recursion there, something like count(num, base): if already_Counted: return already elsE: count_and_store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use divmod instead of the nested loop

```
def count_var(n,m):
  r=[]
  for mi in m[::-1]:
    n,c=divmod(n,mi)
    r.insert(0,c)
  r.insert(0,n)
  return r

print(count_var(719, [3,6,5]))
```

Divmod does basically division and modulo in once